# Error: can't set header after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have two schemas, one for user and one for friendship system (follow system)

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {

email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true
},

password:String,

profile: {
    fullname: String,
    gender: String,
    role: {type: String, default: 'Autorizado'},
    country: String },
});
```

and this for friend system

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Friendship', {
    follower: String,
    followed: String
});
```

I'm using passport to auth my users... the problem is that I want lo load the user information and the friend information related to the user globally using res.locals I make this happen using 2 functions in login post route....

```
router.post('/login', userController.postLogin,friendController.getFollow);
```

this is my postlogin function

```
exports.postLogin = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('errors', { msg: info.message });
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      req.flash('success', { msg: 'Success! You are logged in.' });
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  })
  (req, res, next);
};
```

When I try to execute this code everything goes fine but when I log in I get the header error please how can I solved this or other way to get the user and follow information and use it in every view?.

**EDIT 3:** only works in the next two views

**Single User page**

```
<%= info.profile.fullname %>
<br>
<%= info.email %>
<br>
<%= info.profile.country %>
<br>
<%= user.follow %>
<br>
<% if(user && (user._id != info.id)){ %>
<br>
<form action="/follow/<%= info._id %>" method="post">
<button type="submit">Follow</button></form>
<%}%>
<br>
<a href="/users">atras</a>
```

**List of Registered User**

```
<%if (user) {%>
<h1>Hola <%= user.profile.fullname %> </h1>
<%}%>
<br>
<% users.forEach(function (user) {%>
<a href="/users/<%= user._id %>"><p><%= user.profile.fullname %></p></a>
<%});%>
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

This is my **index** and in this view the user.follow doesn't work

```
<%if (!user) {%>
<a href="/signup">sign up</a>
<br>
<a href="/login">login</a>
<%} else { %>
<h1>Hola <%= user.profile.fullname %> Eres lo Maximo</h1>

<a href="/profile">perfil</a>
<br>
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
<br>
<%}%>
<br>
```

[Lista de Usuarios](/users)

**EDIT 4:** new deserializeUser config.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
User.findById(id, function(err, user) {

FF.find({ follower:id }, function(err, follow) {
user.follow = follow;
});
done(err, user);
});
});
```

**EDIT 5:** This is my route code

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index');
});

router.get('/login', userController.getLogin);
router.post('/login', userController.postLogin);
router.get('/logout', userController.logout);
router.get('/signup', userController.getSignup);
router.post('/signup', userController.postSignup);
router.get('/profile', passportConf.isAuthenticated, userController.getAccount);
router.post('/profile', passportConf.isAuthenticated, userController.postUpdateProfile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had `friendController.getFollow` which would've worked only for the request of `'/login'` page, so the `follow` object wouldn't have been *persistently* available on other routes. To fix that you had to put all that code inside the `passport.deserializeUser` function.

Inside the `passport.deserializeUser` function you could only call `done` once so you had to put the logic to find `follow` inside the callback of `User.find` so that you could attach `follow` to `user`.

This allowed you to remove the `friendController.getFollow` from your `'/login'` route which I think was the cause of your error.

Comment: my friend, I have one question, I only can use user.follow in 2 views could you help me with this problem ?. i updated  the code

Comment: Sure, if I can. Ask it as another question and describe it in as much detail as possible. Separate independent questions help other users and future visitors as well.

Comment: oh ok, I updated this let me create another question